# Sum of RVs converges in probability

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

$X_n \xrightarrow{i.p.} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{i.p.} Y$. Show that $X_n+Y_n \xrightarrow{i.p.} X+Y$.  Here's what I have:

- I know if numerical sequences, or sequences of functions, I would conclude that for any given $\epsilon > 0$, $|X_n+Y_n-X-Y|\leq |X_n-X|+|Y_n-Y|\leq \epsilon$ with proper choice of $\epsilon$ for $X_n$ and $Y_n$.
- $P\big(|X_n+Y_n-X-Y|\leq \epsilon\big)\leq P\big(|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon \;\cap\;|Y_n-Y|\leq \epsilon\big)=P\big(|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon\big)P\big(|Y_n-Y|\leq \epsilon\big)$

But that just gives me an upper bound. Any hint on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no reason I can see why your inequality

$$P\big(|X_n+Y_n-X-Y|\leq \epsilon\big)\leq P\big(|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon \;\cap\;|Y_n-Y|\leq \epsilon\big)$$ should hold. That's saying that if $a+b<\epsilon$ then $a<\epsilon$ and $b<\epsilon$, which is not so.

But the inequality also seems irrelevant. Saying $X_n\to X$ in probability says that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to0$.

Hint: If $|a|\le\epsilon/2$ and $|b|\le\epsilon/2$ then $|a+b|\le\epsilon$. So if $|a+b|>\epsilon$ then $|a|>\epsilon/2$ *or* $|b|>\epsilon/2$. So $$P(|X_n+Y_n-(X+Y)|>\epsilon)\le P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon/2)+P(|Y_n-Y|>\epsilon/2).$$

Comment: Not actually clear why your inequality holds at the end

Comment: @ToniAz If $A\subset B\cup C$ then $P(A)\le P(B)+P(C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fact: A sequence converges in probability iff every subsequence has a further subsequence converging almost everywhere.